# xargs fails when a filename contains white space

Tags: linux, find, whitespace, filenames, xargs

I am using `xargs` to search a content in a file but `xargs` fails because of whitespace in file name. What is the reason behind this? Anyway, I can acheive it by using `-exec` in the `find` command.

Comment: Can you please post an example of the failing command? It's probably not xargs that is failing but the command that it is calling

Comment: `xargs` scans its standard input for file names to work on. If a filename contains a whitespace, then it appears as two tokens, _unless_ that whitespace is escaped or the filename is enclosed in quotes, just as if you would directly feed some filename into any cli utility. This is not an `xargs` specific issue, it is how your shell environment behaves.

Answer (score 3):

When using `find` and `xargs` on files that may contain whitespace, use `-print0` with `find` and `-0` with `xargs`, that way `xargs` receives the file names separated by `nul` instead and will call the utility with the correct arguments.

For example, looking for "string" in all files in the current directory (and below):

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "string"
```

See the manuals for both `find` and `xargs`.